# I want to delete colors added in Terminal

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal

I added color on the gnome-terminal as in the picture and now I want to delete the custom colors added

[image]

I want to have the colors as in this picture

[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Remove from where?

Comment: I think it's clear this question is asking how to reverse changes to the terminal text color in a GNOME Terminal profile. If that's not what's being asked, please let us know @Farhad. Otherwise, I think we can keep this question open, and answer it. (I don't currently have access to a GNOME-based Ubuntu system to write a good answer, or I'd be doing that myself right about now.)

Answer (score 2):

*Finally, found it*. You need to install `dconf-tools` to do this. Install it with the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

or by clicking the big download button

[image: Install via the software center]

After installation, start the `dconf-editor` by typing `dconf-editor` in the dash and select it to start.

Go to *org* → *gtk* → *settings* → *color-chooser* and set the *custom-colors* value to `[]`, replacing the existing long string. To replace the string, click on the value/existing string.

Now open gnome-terminal to see that the color is gone.

Comment: @Farhad I have updated the answer. I think, it will solve the problem.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your problem. That is a good way of giving thanks