# Unable to delete custom colors under Appearance/Background

Tags: themes, customization, colors

The "*Background*" panel in "*System Settings/Appearance*", allows to select the background color of the desktop, solid or with a gradient.

There, the "*Pick a color*" window allows to choice a color from a standard palette, or a custom color.

Whenever you select a custom color, a corresponding sample is shown under the standard palette.

It happens, however, that there is no obvious way to delete a custom color, so the line of samples grows accordingly.

So there is a problem when you want to delete a number of custom colors.

The data of these colors, which are associated with the user, are supposedly in the home directory, but I've not find any reference to them.

Can you suggest me  where to look?

Comment: If you are looking to change colours, install Gnome Color Chooser `sudo apt-get install gnome-color-chooser`

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is actually the same given to the question [I want to delete colors added in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203417/i-want-to-delete-colors-added-in-terminal), where it is suggested to install the configuration editor `dconf-tools`,
then execute `dconf-editor`, expand the tree `org/gtk/settings/color-chooser/` and delete the values of the `custom-colors` key.